# Передать html код через JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Здравствуйте!

На сервере формируется строка в виде html кода. Например:

```
$html = '<div class="cats"></div>';
```

Можно ли эти данные отправить в виде JSON?

При использовании:

```
echo json_encode($html);
```

Получается:

```
"<\/div>"
```

Comment: так всё ок, правда можно так и отправить как html просто тип входных данных указав как html в функции `ajax`,`post`,`get` если это jquery.

Comment: @Naumov, Нужно именно в JSON, чтобы отправить дополнительно данные для js скрипта

Comment: Да и так пойдёт в ответе не будут учитываться символы экранирования т.е. `result.html` вернёт приемлимый текст.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '<div class="cats"></div>';
$a  = json_encode($html);
$b = json_decode($a);
print_r($b);
```

На выходе в переменной `$b` имеем `'<div class="cats"></div>';` На стороне приема данных используйте `json_decode`. Проверялось [здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com)